# Can't run application with ./ child process Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ngrok

I'm trying to launch Ngrok using Node JS the child process, unfortuantly this isn't working as it thinks the `./` is a non recognised command... how could I resolve this? it works from my terminal within the directory I'm in...

```js
const os = new os_func()

os.execCommand(`./ngrok http file:///my-file`).then(res => {
  console.log(res)
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

My OS function is exposed and exported as...

```js
function os_func() {
  this.execCommand = function (cmd) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error)
          return
        }
        resolve(stdout)
      })
    })
  }
}
```

The error I get is:

> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: Can you try `${path.resolve(__dirname + "/ngrok")} http file:///my-file`

Comment: the ngrok executable is within my directory, so I need to run it with `./ngrok` which works if I do this from my terminal... your suggestion outputs: `C:\Users\USER\Desktop\web-projects\speech-bot.\ngrok http file:///my-file` which is a **Command failed** error now

Comment: If you're getting `C:\Users\USER\Desktop\web-projects\speech-bot.\ngrok` with the `.` in it, then you're not doing what the first comment here suggested.

Comment: I'm not getting that, I'm getting: `./C:\Users\USER\Desktop\web-projects\speech-bot\ngrok http file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/web-proj
ects/speech-bot/src/web` from the following command: `./${path.resolve(__dirname + "/ngrok")} http file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/web-projects/speech-bot/src/web`, ngrok is in the directory where I'm running the command thus the `./`